# Rails: Enumerable#group_by with Delegation makes too many DB calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, group-by

Here is the code:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :name, :to => :video_type, :prefix => true, :allow_nil => true
  belongs_to :athlete, :class_name => "Athlete"
end

class Athlete < User
  has_many :videos
end
```

Console:

```
a = Athlete.last
a.videos.group_by(&:video_type_name)
  VideoType Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "video_types".* FROM "video_types" WHERE "video_types"."id" = 12 LIMIT 1
Called from: app/models/video.rb:9:in `video_type_name'
  VideoType Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "video_types".* FROM "video_types" WHERE "video_types"."id" = 14 LIMIT 1
Called from: app/models/video.rb:9:in `video_type_name'
  VideoType Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "video_types".* FROM "video_types" WHERE "video_types"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
Called from: app/models/video.rb:9:in `video_type_name'
  VideoType Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "video_types".* FROM "video_types" WHERE "video_types"."id" = 9 LIMIT 1
Called from: app/models/video.rb:9:in `video_type_name'
  VideoType Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "video_types".* FROM "video_types" WHERE "video_types"."id" = 11 LIMIT 1
Called from: app/models/video.rb:9:in `video_type_name'
  VideoType Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "video_types".* FROM "video_types" WHERE "video_types"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
Called from: app/models/video.rb:9:in `video_type_name'
  VideoType Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "video_types".* FROM "video_types" WHERE "video_types"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
```

Is there any way to reduce this to just one database call?

Comment: Does `Video` `belongs_to :video_type`? Try with `a.videos.includes(:video_type).group_by(&:video_type_name)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `includes` or `join`. This would create a `SQL` query that create the joins between the tables and group by whatever you like.

```
a.includes(:videos => :video_types).group('video_types.video_type_name')
```